# How can I copy one file from one folder to another within an Azure Fileshare using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, fileshare

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 using Azure;
 using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
 using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models;
 
 namespace SpeakerDocumentsMigration
 {
     class Program
     {
        static string connectionstring = "";
        static string filesharename = "";
        static string Sourcepath = ""; 
        static string DestPath = "";
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShareFileClient sourcefile = new ShareFileClient(connectionstring, filesharename,Sourcepath);
 
            ShareFileClient destfile = new ShareFileClient(connectionstring, filesharename, DestPath);
 
            destfile.StartCopy(sourcefile.Uri);    

        }
    }
}
```

Seems like above code is not working, assuming I enter values for all the variables declared.

Can someone please guide how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried the below code and can copy one file from one folder to another within one Azure Fileshare using C# dot net.***

**Code** :

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpeakerDocumentsMigration
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionstring = "<storage_connec_string>";
        static string filesharename = "<fileshare_name>";
        static string SourcePath = "<sourcefolder_name/sourcefile_name.txt>"; 
        static string DestPath = "<destinationfolder_name/destinationfile_name.txt>"; 

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClient(connectionstring, filesharename);
            ShareDirectoryClient sourceDirectory = shareClient.GetDirectoryClient(Path.GetDirectoryName(SourcePath));
            ShareDirectoryClient destDirectory = shareClient.GetDirectoryClient(Path.GetDirectoryName(DestPath));

            if (await sourceDirectory.ExistsAsync() && await destDirectory.ExistsAsync())
            {
                ShareFileClient sourceFile = sourceDirectory.GetFileClient(Path.GetFileName(SourcePath));
                ShareFileClient destFile = destDirectory.GetFileClient(Path.GetFileName(DestPath));

                if (await sourceFile.ExistsAsync())
                {
                    ShareFileProperties properties = await sourceFile.GetPropertiesAsync();
                    if (properties.CopyStatus == CopyStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File already copied.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await destFile.StartCopyAsync(sourceFile.Uri);

                        await WaitForCopyToCompleteAsync(destFile);

                        Console.WriteLine("File copied successfully.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Source file does not exist.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source or destination folder does not exist.");
            }
        }

        static async Task WaitForCopyToCompleteAsync(ShareFileClient fileClient)
        {
            ShareFileProperties properties = await fileClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
            while (properties.CopyStatus == CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); 
                properties = await fileClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully and copies one file from one folder to another in Fileshare.

[image]

***I got the copied data from one file from one folder to another in file share at the Azure portal as below.***

[image]

**Source folder file** :

[image]

**Destination folder file** :
[image]

Comment: Hi @Dasari, I tried your code but getting error - 'The specified resource does not exist. although the file is present in the file share

Comment: @Anshul76 Can you check your files, folders and connection string are correctly added to the code?

Comment: @Anshul76 I think you didn't **upload a destination file to the fileshare** in the storage at the **Azure portal**.

You need to upload a file to the destination folder in fileshare before going to run the above code.

Comment: @Anshul76 Have you added the **file name** in the **code**?

Comment: @Anshul76 Check if you added the files like [this](https://i.imgur.com/eywlQ2N.png) in the code.

Comment: Hi @Dasari, Can you please tell if we can add rollback in this code? I am copying multiple files from one fileshare to another, if anything goes wrong can we add a rollback to revert all the file transfer?